# Swift Playgrounds iPad - parse from json Financial Modelling Prep API

Tags: json, swift, swift-playground

G’day
I’m trying to pull financial data from the FMP API.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation

let url = URL(string: "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/income-statement/AAPL?apikey=XXXX")

var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept") //error flag
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!)
        return
    }
    guard let data = data else {
        print("Data is empty")
        return
    }
    
    let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    print(json)
}

task.resume() //error flag
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true //error flag
```

This is the code they suggest for swift, but I’m getting errors of “expressions are not allowed at the top level” when I attempt this in Playgrounds on iPad. Any idea what’s going wrong?

Appreciate any help. Cheers

Comment: This executes fine for me on an iPad. Are you sure you are using a playground and not an app in Playgrounds?

Comment: Hmm that’s quite peculiar. How did you test if you don’t mind me asking? EDIT: woops yeah I’m using an app in playgrounds. How will that differ?

Comment: You have seen the difference in the error message you got. In a playground you can just run code like this directly but in an app you need to wrap it inside a function (usually that function resides inside a struct or class) and then call that function from some part of your app code.

Comment: Is this your actual code, or code you got from FMP web site ? if not your code show it. As previous comment said, you cannot only have var declaration at top level in modules. If you are doing an app with classes and struct definitions, the code lines (task.resume() for example must be inside functions. This code work perfectly as is in Playground as a playground.

Comment: Ahhh okay I’m starting to understand. Yes this is the actual code I’m running. What I really want to do is parse certain lines of the resulting JSON array and store the values. Thanks for the guidance. Very new to coding